# Type error when using getenv unless it's in parenthesis

Tags: kdb

Can someone help me understand why this returns a type error...

```
getenv`SOME_ENV_VARIABLE ~ ""
```

But this does not...

```
(getenv`SOME_ENV_VARIABLE) ~ ""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kdb reads left-of-right (not left-to-right) so your first statement is interpreted as:

```
`SOME_ENV_VARIABLE ~ ""
```

which returns a boolean. Then you're doing:

```
getenv 0b
```

which is the wrong type.

Your parentheses are forcing the getenv to apply to  `` `SOME_ENV_VARIABLE ``, an alternative way to achieve it is to do:

```
getenv[`SOME_ENV_VARIABLE] ~ ""
```

Comment: for further details: https://code.kx.com/q4m3/4_Operators/